# What do they mean when they say "a blue $3$-regular subgraph"?

Tags: graph-theory

In page 4 of the following http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/D.Kuehn/RamseyGreg.pdf the text says

> In any graph the number of vertices with odd degree must be even. For this reason there cannot exist a red 5-regular subgraph of $K_9$ or a blue 3-regular subgraph of $K_9$. This implies that in a complete 2-coloured graph of order nine there must be at least one vertex which is incident to at least six red or at least four blue edges.

I don't understand why "there cannot exist..." and why in turn "This implies that...". For example, if I take inside $K_9$ a $K_4$ and paint it all blue, don't I get a blue $3$-regular subgraph? It might be that I don't understand what the author means by "blue $3$-regular subgraph". Could someone clarify?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense indeed.  Is it possible that the author means a __spanning__ subgraph of $K_9$ (i.e. a red $5$-regular graph on 9 vertices) ?

Comment: @manuellafond I honestly have no idea. My graph theory is nonexistent.

Comment: I too am stumped by this, but there is another way to go about showing that $R(4, 3) \leq 9$.  A famous Ramsey-theoretic inequality is that $R(s, t) \leq R(s-1, t) + R(s, t-1) - 1$.  Applying this, we get $R(4, 3) \leq R(3, 3) + R(4, 2) - 1$.  It's famous that $R(3, 3) = 6$, and it's pretty easy to show from scratch that $R(4, 2) = 4$.

Comment: As far as your original question goes, however, I'm likewise confused why there cannot exist a $5$-regular subgraph of $K_9$.  My graph theory isn't the best, but if I'm not mistaken, there will always exist a complete subgraph $K_x \subset K_y$ whenever $x<y$, and $K_x$ is $x$-regular...

Comment: @KajHansen I thought the bound was $R(s-1,t)+R(s,t-1)$, not  $R(s-1,t)+R(s,t-1)-1$

Comment: I should quickly add that the inequality above holds with the $-1$ *only if* $R(s-1, t)$ and $R(s, t-1)$ are both even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He means you cannot find a subset of edges **that includes all $9$ vertices of $K_9$** that is $3$ or $5$ regular.  You certainly can find a $5$-regular subgraph of $K_9$-just take $K_6$.  What he really wants to do is justify the next sentence-that in any two coloring of $K_9$ there is a vertex with either six or more red edges or a vertex with four or more blue edges.  As each vertex of $K_9$ has degree $8$, the only way this could fail would be if you could partition $K_9$ into a $5$-regular red piece and a $3$-regular blue piece.  The parity argument is enough to show this is not possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the author were explicit that subgraph means spanning subgraph?!!! I wonder if he'll be consistent.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  that would be nice.  I had to read it a few times to realize what he needed for the next sentence.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial reaction. But I couldn't believe there was no discussion *anywhere* about such a hypothesis. Thanks for confirming!!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a $K_9$ and paint the edges of a $K_4$ all blue (and the remaining edges are painted red, say - remember that each edge needs to be painted one color or another), then the resulting subgraph consisting of all blue edges is not a 3-regular graph on 9 vertices.  The blue graph, which is defined to be the graph induced by exactly the set of blue edges, is a graph consisting of a $K_4$ and 5 isolated vertices, and hence does not contain a 3-regular subgraph on the 9 vertices.

Observe that in $K_9$, each vertex has 8 edges incident to it.  Fix a particular vertex $v$, and suppose it has $b(v)$ blue edges and $r(v)$ red edges incident to it. Then $b(v)+r(v)=8$, for each vertex $v$.  The author says that in any red-blue coloring of the edges of $K_9$, either $b(v) \ge 4$ or $r(v) \ge 6$ for some vertex $v$.  For if that is not the case, then every vertex has at most 3 blue and at most 5 red edges incident to it, and hence every vertex has exactly 3 blue and exactly 5 red edges incident to it (by the requirement $b(v)+r(v)=8$), which is a contradiction since there does not exist a 3-regular graph on 9 vertices (and since there does not exist a 5-regular graph on 9 vertices).